# Comparación de cadenas en Oracle

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

tengo una situación que me esta complicando la existencia. Tengo dos tablas, en la tabla 1 tengo una columna llamada `Numero_de_poliza`, en la tabla 2 tengo una columna que se llama igual `Numero_de_poliza`. En la Tabla 1, en dicha columna obviamente contiene el respectivo número de póliza de cada registro que existe en la tabla y en la tabla 2 es el mismo caso que la tabla uno.
La situación radica en que en la tabla 2 existen algunos Número de Pólizas con una llamada "Renovación" esta renovación consiste en agregarle un numero consecutivo dividido por un "-", este numero consecutivo depende a un rango de fecha.

Ejemplo:

```
Tabla 2 - Numero_de_poliza: 12348-1
Tabla 2 - Numero_de_poliza: 899674-4

Tabla 1 - Numero_de_poliza: 12348
Tabla 1 - Numero_de_poliza: 899674
```

Lo curioso de esto es que en la tabla 1 puede venir el mismo número de póliza pero sin su número consecutivo, la complicación es la siguiente: ¿Como puedo igualar dicho número consecutivo de la tabla 2 a la tabla 1 y que se pueda saber que numero es para que en el caso de que el rango de fecha exija un cambio de número consecutivo, se pueda hacer?

Mi idea es igualar ambas cadenas del Número de Póliza y ver si coinciden, después saber si la cadena tiene el numero consecutivo en la tabla 2 y después agregarle el consecutivo correspondiente, pero no se como hacerlo.

¡Ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Daniel

Puedes usar una expresión regular de PL/SQL para solucionar tu problema.

```
SELECT
REGEXP_SUBSTR('899674-4','[^-]+') REGEXPR_SUBSTR 
FROM DUAL;
/* Resultado 899674 */
```

Así volverás a tener el número de póliza si el carácter agregado y podrás hacer la comparación que necesitas.